# Conditionally execure SQL within a select statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement as below. I have a master table as master and three other tables as below,
Merchant,
Customer,
Device

I want to select from these table based on a condition and pick from Merchant or Customer or Device,

```
SELECT count(chkitems.alert_id) AS alert_cnt, chkitems.blacklist_id, 
sum(case when fm.alert_id is NOT null then 1 else 0 end) as fraud_cnt
FROM 
Condition 1: 
***Merchant mid INNER JOIN CHECK_BLACKLIST_ITEMS chkitems ON mid.Marchant_id = chkitems.blacklist_id***
Condition 2:
***Customer cust INNER JOIN CHECK_BLACKLIST_ITEMS chkitems ON cust.Customer_id = chkitems.blacklist_id***
Condition 3:
***Device dev INNER JOIN CHECK_BLACKLIST_ITEMS chkitems ON dev.Device_id = chkitems.blacklist_id***
LEFT JOIN FRAUDMARKING_VIEW fm ON (chkitems.alert_id = fm.alert_id)
GROUP BY chkitems.blacklist_id;
```

Note the Condition1, Condition2, Condition3 mentioned. There are the statements, I am not sure what to fill in. Or is it not even possible?

Database is oracle. I want to plugin this into a jasper report, so this kind of select is query is needed for it to work based on our current design

Sorry for the ignorance which is evident in the question asked, but pls understand.

Comment: This looks like you're trying to use polymorphic foreign-keys (which is an anti-pattern: don't do it) - Is `chkitems.blacklist_id` actually defined as a `FOREIGN KEY`?

Comment: It is not a foreign key

Comment: So how do you know if any given `blacklist_id` value corresponds to `Merchant_id`, `Customer_id`, or something else? Are you keeping `Merchant_id` and `Customer_id` values globally-unique (perhaps with UUID? or shared `SEQUENCE` object?) But if you're using `IDENTITY` (`GENERATED AS...`) in each of those tables then what you're asking is impossible because there's no way of identifying exactly what object the `blacklist_id` value refers to...

Comment: What the reason you want select data from these three other tables (Merchant, Customer, Device)? As i see, you don't use in the query any columns from these tables.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `UNION ALL` to concatenate all the optional tables (since you only want an ID column from each) and use a `WHERE` clause to filter them:

```sql
SELECT count(chkitems.alert_id) AS alert_cnt,
       chkitems.blacklist_id, 
       sum(case when fm.alert_id is NOT null then 1 else 0 end) as fraud_cnt
FROM   ( SELECT marchant_id AS id FROM Merchant WHERE some_condition = 'TRUE' UNION ALL
         SELECT Customer_id       FROM Customer WHERE some_condition = 'TRUE' UNION ALL
         SELECT device_id         FROM Device   WHERE some_condition = 'TRUE' ) i
       INNER JOIN CHECK_BLACKLIST_ITEMS chkitems
       ON i.id = chkitems.blacklist_id
       LEFT OUTER JOIN FRAUDMARKING_VIEW fm
       ON (chkitems.alert_id = fm.alert_id)
GROUP BY chkitems.blacklist_id;
```

Or you could use `EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT count(c.alert_id) AS alert_cnt,
       c.blacklist_id, 
       sum(case when fm.alert_id is NOT null then 1 else 0 end) as fraud_cnt
FROM   CHECK_BLACKLIST_ITEMS c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN FRAUDMARKING_VIEW fm
       ON (c.alert_id = fm.alert_id)
WHERE  EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   Merchant m
         WHERE  c.blacklist_id = m.marchant_id
         AND    some_condition = 'TRUE'
       )
OR     EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   Customer x
         WHERE  c.blacklist_id = x.customer_id
         AND    some_condition = 'TRUE'
       )
OR     EXISTS (
         SELECT 1
         FROM   Device d
         WHERE  c.blacklist_id = d.device_id
         AND    some_condition = 'TRUE'
       )
GROUP BY chkitems.blacklist_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without some sample data it is hard to tell what it's all about, but we could try to guess the context.
Here are the tables involved as I assume they could be alike:

```sql
WITH
    check_blacklist_items (ID, ALERT_ID, BLACKLIST_ID) AS
        (   Select 1, 'A01', 132 From Dual Union All
            Select 2, 'A07', 140 From Dual Union All
            Select 3, 'A23', 140 From Dual Union All
            Select 4, 'A44', 132 From Dual Union All
            Select 5, 'A45', 188 From Dual 
        ),
```

| ID | ALERT_ID | BLACKLIST_ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A01 | 132 |
| 2 | A07 | 140 |
| 3 | A23 | 140 |
| 4 | A44 | 132 |
| 5 | A45 | 188 |

```sql
    merchant (MERCHANT_ID, NOTE) AS
        (   Select 112, 'Merchant 112' From Dual Union All
            Select 129, 'Merchant 129' From Dual Union All
            Select 140, 'Merchant 140' From Dual Union All
            Select 156, 'Merchant 156' From Dual 
        ),
```

| MERCHANT_ID | NOTE |
| --- | --- |
| 112 | Merchant 112 |
| 129 | Merchant 129 |
| 140 | Merchant 140 |
| 156 | Merchant 156 |

```sql
    customer (CUSTOMER_ID, NOTE) AS
        (   Select 132, 'Customer 132' From Dual Union All
            Select 133, 'Customer 133' From Dual Union All
            Select 134, 'Customer 134' From Dual  
        ),
```

| CUSTOMER_ID | NOTE |
| --- | --- |
| 132 | Customer 132 |
| 133 | Customer 133 |
| 134 | Customer 134 |

```sql
    device (DEVICE_ID, NOTE) AS
        (   Select 180, 'Device 180' From Dual Union All
            Select 188, 'Device 188' From Dual Union All
            Select 190, 'Device 190' From Dual  
        ),
```

| DEVICE_ID | NOTE |
| --- | --- |
| 180 | Device 180 |
| 188 | Device 188 |
| 190 | Device 190 |

Assuming that the fraudmarking_view is used for data comparison, as a sample, I created it like below:

```sql
    fraudmarking_view (ALERT_ID, OTHER_COLS) AS
        (   Select 'A01', null From Dual Union All
            Select 'A07', null From Dual Union All
            Select 'A44', null From Dual Union All
            Select 'A45', null From Dual 
        ),
```

| ALERT_ID | OTHER_COLS |
| --- | --- |
| A01 |  |
| A07 |  |
| A44 |  |
| A45 |  |

Now we could combine all of the above into one joined dataset (named it grid)

```sql
    grid AS
        (   Select      chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID, chkitems.ALERT_ID, fm.ALERT_ID "FM_ALERT_ID",
                        Case When mid.MERCHANT_ID Is Not Null Then mid.MERCHANT_ID End "MERCHANT_ID",
                        Case When custid.CUSTOMER_ID Is Not Null Then custid.CUSTOMER_ID End "CUSTOMER_ID",
                        Case When devid.DEVICE_ID Is Not Null Then devid.DEVICE_ID End "DEVICE_ID"
            From        check_blacklist_items chkitems
            Left Join   merchant mid ON(mid.MERCHANT_ID = chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID) 
            Left Join   customer custid ON(custid.CUSTOMER_ID = chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID) 
            Left Join   device devid ON(devid.DEVICE_ID = chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID) 
            Left Join   fraudmarking_view fm ON(fm.ALERT_ID = chkitems.ALERT_ID)
        )
```

... it looks like ...

| BLACKLIST_ID | ALERT_ID | FM_ALERT_ID | MERCHANT_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | DEVICE_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | A01 | A01 |  | 132 |  |
| 132 | A44 | A44 |  | 132 |  |
| 140 | A23 |  | 140 |  |  |
| 140 | A07 | A07 | 140 |  |  |
| 188 | A45 | A45 |  |  | 188 |

... if we use your starting select command on the grid dataset grouped by BLACKLIST_ID...

```sql
SELECT    BLACKLIST_ID, Count(ALERT_ID) "ALERT_CNT",
          Sum(Case When FM_ALERT_ID Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 END) "FRAUD_CNT"
FROM      grid
GROUP BY  BLACKLIST_ID
```

... the result should be like below.

| BLACKLIST_ID | ALERT_CNT | FRAUD_CNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 140 | 2 | 1 |
| 188 | 1 | 1 |
| 132 | 2 | 2 |

ADDITION
If you want to know where was data picked from and if there could be same IDs among the three blacklist tables you should add another column to the grid (PICKED_FROM)

```sql
    grid AS
        (   Select      chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID, chkitems.ALERT_ID, fm.ALERT_ID "FM_ALERT_ID",
                        Case When mid.MERCHANT_ID Is Not Null Then mid.MERCHANT_ID End "MERCHANT_ID",
                        Case When custid.CUSTOMER_ID Is Not Null Then custid.CUSTOMER_ID End "CUSTOMER_ID",
                        Case When devid.DEVICE_ID Is Not Null Then devid.DEVICE_ID End "DEVICE_ID",
            Case When mid.MERCHANT_ID Is Not Null And
                      custid.CUSTOMER_ID Is Not Null And 
                      devid.DEVICE_ID Is Not Null Then 'MERCHANT, CUSTOMER, DEVICE'
                When mid.MERCHANT_ID Is Not Null And
                     custid.CUSTOMER_ID Is Not Null Then 'MERCHANT, CUSTOMER'
                When mid.MERCHANT_ID Is Not Null And
                     devid.DEVICE_ID Is Not Null Then 'MERCHANT, DEVICE'
                When custid.CUSTOMER_ID Is Not Null And
                     devid.DEVICE_ID Is Not Null Then 'CUSTOMER, DEVICE'
                When mid.MERCHANT_ID Is Not Null Then 'MERCHANT'
                When custid.CUSTOMER_ID Is Not Null Then 'CUSTOMER'
                When devid.DEVICE_ID Is Not Null Then 'DEVICE'
            End "PICKED_FROM"
            From        check_blacklist_items chkitems
            Left Join   merchant mid ON(mid.MERCHANT_ID = chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID) 
            Left Join   customer custid ON(custid.CUSTOMER_ID = chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID) 
            Left Join   device devid ON(devid.DEVICE_ID = chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID) 
            Left Join   fraudmarking_view fm ON(fm.ALERT_ID = chkitems.ALERT_ID)
      Order By    chkitems.BLACKLIST_ID
```

grid dataset now is like here:

| BLACKLIST_ID | ALERT_ID | FM_ALERT_ID | MERCHANT_ID | CUSTOMER_ID | DEVICE_ID | PICKED_FROM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | A01 | A01 |  | 132 |  | CUSTOMER |
| 132 | A44 | A44 |  | 132 |  | CUSTOMER |
| 140 | A23 |  | 140 |  |  | MERCHANT |
| 140 | A07 | A07 | 140 |  |  | MERCHANT |
| 188 | A45 | A45 |  |  | 188 | DEVICE |

Now you can include that column in your select and group by...

```sql
SELECT    BLACKLIST_ID, Count(ALERT_ID) "ALERT_CNT",
          Sum(Case When FM_ALERT_ID Is Not Null Then 1 Else 0 END) "FRAUD_CNT",
          PICKED_FROM
FROM      grid
GROUP BY  BLACKLIST_ID, PICKED_FROM
ORDER BY  BLACKLIST_ID
```

... resulting as:

| BLACKLIST_ID | ALERT_CNT | FRAUD_CNT | PICKED_FROM |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 132 | 2 | 2 | CUSTOMER |
| 140 | 2 | 1 | MERCHANT |
| 188 | 1 | 1 | DEVICE |